# import csv with pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

Please am using this common; data = pd.read_csv('diabetes_train.csv') to import my csv-file but the result is not clear

```
Number of times pregnant;Plasma glucose concentration;Diastolic blood pressure;Triceps skin fold thickness;2-Hour serum insulin;Body mass index;Age;Class
0   1;85;66;29;0;26.6;31;negative
1   1;89;66;23;94;28.1;21;negative
2   5;116;74;0;0;25.6;30;negative
3   10;115;0;0;0;35.3;29;negative
4   4;110;92;0;0;37.6;30;negative
... ...
662 1;128;88;39;110;36.5;37;positive
663 0;123;72;0;0;36.3;52;positive
664 6;190;92;0;0;35.5;66;positive
665 9;170;74;31;0;44;43;positive
666 1;126;60;0;0;30.1;47;positive
667 rows × 1 columns
```

the values are seperated from their respective columns,what should i do?

Comment: Set the separator to a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: `pd.read_csv('diabetes_train.csv',sep=';')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the separator parameter [**`sep=…`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to a semicolon (`;`):

```
data = pd.read_csv('diabetes_train.csv', sep=';')
```

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
>>> data
   Number of times pregnant  Plasma glucose concentration  Diastolic blood pressure  ...  Body mass index  Age     Class
0                         1                            85                        66  ...             26.6   31  negative
1                         1                            89                        66  ...             28.1   21  negative
2                         5                           116                        74  ...             25.6   30  negative
3                        10                           115                         0  ...             35.3   29  negative
4                         4                           110                        92  ...             37.6   30  negative
5                         1                           128                        88  ...             36.5   37  positive
6                         0                           123                        72  ...             36.3   52  positive
7                         6                           190                        92  ...             35.5   66  positive
8                         9                           170                        74  ...             44.0   43  positive
9                         1                           126                        60  ...             30.1   47  positive

[10 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: great, thanks willem,it worked...